# What will happen during the switching between Apps on Android?

Tags: android, memory-management

E.g. When I switch from App **A** to App **B**, I thought the App **A** would become a "cached background process". Does this mean the memory used by App **A**'s is copied to "disk(SD Card)"? Is the memory occupied by **A** available to use by other Apps?

Further, how to recover App **A** when I switch back? What cause the recovering delay if there is any?

Comment: Read this: developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html and most importantly, about the activity and process lifecycles.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

App A will stay in memory so long as Android leaves it there. If you want to direct your apps functions through this transition you need to override OnPause() and OnResume().
eg.

```
    @Override
    protected void onPause(){
    // YOUR CODE HERE
    super.onPause();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume(){
    // YOUR CODE HERE
    super.onResume();
    }
```

Onpause is thrown when you press the home button, get a call etc. it gives you a chance to stop your threads (tell your app to stop working) and do anything you have to before the focus is lost. It is not a great time to save data because that can take too long and a user will expect the app to disappear immediately.

OnResume is thrown when you open your app again, this is where you start your thread again (tell your app to start working)

Comment: Thank you for your answer! A few confusion. First, what do ``super.onPause()" and ``super.onResume" do? Second, by default, the data used by applications would be lost during switching, right?

Comment: super.onPause() is a method that will run when the app goes into pause mode. ie. you press the home button, get a call etc. It gives you a chance to do anything necessary before your app loses focus. super.onResume() runs when you open up the app again.